# How to apply dynamic style to AMP page?

Tags: css, amp-html, accelerated-mobile-page, google-amp

Currently we have in our web site we have one slider as following.

[image: 1]
[image: 2]

As we can see that position of pointer(arrow of asking price) is changed based on `Fair Condition, Good Condition and Asking Price` value. This value comes through api and then we bind it here using javascript. And we calculate position of pointer(arrow of asking price) using some function and then using `left` we will set position.

e.g. For first image value for style attribute of tag which is showing pointer is `left:  85%` and image value for style attribute of tag which is showing pointer is `left:  40%`

Now problem is when we are converting this page to AMP, we are not able to set position of pointer based on api response.

The one possible way is create 100 class of something like this

```
.left-21{left: 21%}
.left-51{left: 51%}
```

And according response from api we can add this class to div(which is showing pointer) using amp-bind. But it is not right way.

Is there any other way we can accomplish this in amp?

Comment: is asking price position left more than 92%?

Comment: @BachchaSingh may be possible, is asking price position left vary between 1 to 100%

Answer (score 2):

Use [UI Components > Form Elements > Range Input](https://www.ampstart.com/components#form-elements)

```
<input type="range" min="1" max="100" value="20" class="slider" id="myRange">
```

Change the value on input with AMP-BIND

```css
    .slider {
max-width:273px;
    -webkit-appearance: none;
    width: 100%;
    height: 25px;
    background: url(https://s17.postimg.org/z9in37267/image.png) no-repeat 0px 10px;
    outline: none;
    -webkit-transition: .2s;
    transition: opacity .2s;
}


.slider::-webkit-slider-thumb {
    -webkit-appearance: none;
    appearance: none;
    width: 21px;
    height: 31px;
    background: url(https://s17.postimg.org/8og47pke7/image.png) no-repeat;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.slider::-moz-range-thumb {
    width: 25px;
    height: 25px;
    background: url(https://s17.postimg.org/8og47pke7/image.png) no-repeat;
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<input type="range" min="1" max="100" value="20" class="slider" id="myRange">
```

Comment: Perfect, Is there way to move asking price text also with pointer?

Comment: @yajiv share me the fiddle or code-pan of your html and css, so i can check the possibility

Answer (score 0):

You may follow this [page](https://www.ampproject.org/docs/reference/components/amp-dynamic-css-classes) on how to add several dynamic CSS class names onto the `<body>` element of AMP pages. The AMP Dynamic CSS Classes extension adds the `amp-referrer-*` and `amp-viewer` CSS classes onto the  element. Check this *AMP By Example*'s [amp-dynamic-css-classes](https://ampbyexample.com/components/amp-dynamic-css-classes/) example. Be noted that AMP's dynamic CSS classes provided by the [`amp-dynamic-css-class`](https://www.ampproject.org/docs/reference/components/amp-dynamic-css-classes) tag enable boolean logic for a handful of conditions